# How to run multiple pm2 instances each with different cmd args?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a whole bunch of files to parse and transform and I've created a nodejs app for this where I supply stuff like source and target dir as cmd args when I run the app. Now I would like to start a whole bunch of these processes each with different cmd args. With npm I have to do this manually. Can I do this programmatically with pm2? Can I say to pm2 run 10 instances of my app, each instance takes different cmd args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the concept of an [ecosystem](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) file.

A minimal example would be:

```
// worker.js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(process.argv);
}, 1000);
```

```
// ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'Worker 1',
      script: 'worker.js',
      args: 'one two'
    },
    {
      name: 'Worker 2',
      script: 'worker.js',
      args: 'three four'
    }
  ]
};
```

In the same directory simply execute: `pm2 start`

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this. This is so powerful!